# Regex with 6 digits Near each other

Tags: regex

I can have this text:

```
words on this line maybe numbers like 4n1me
words here 123456 other words here.
```

I want to get the 123456 number and not the 4 and 1 from 4n1me.
this regex  [+-]?\d+(?:.\d+)?  with space before and after finds my 123456 number

the problem is where I have spaces like 1 2 3 4 5 6 in my number it only gets the first 1 digit character
how can I modify the regex to ignore the spaces and return 1 2 3 4 5 6?

if I have 123 456 I want to find 123 456 and after I can remove the space to use the digits.

there will always be 6 digits near each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with word boundaries on both sides:

```
[+-]?\b\d+(?: +\d+)*\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrMhkt/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[+-]?`: Match optional `+` or `-` at start
- `\b`: Assert a word boundary
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?: +\d+)*`: Match 1+ space followed by 1+ digits. Match 0 or more of this set.
- `\b`: Assert a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
 [+-]?\b(\d[ ]*){6}
```

The regex creates a Group that matches a `digit` followed by `any number of Spaces` (optional).

This Group is matched `6 times`.

It  only matches if the there's Spaces between the numbers, not letters.